# Статус бар на IE11 (ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Я реализовал статус бар на сайте с помощью следующего кода:

```js
(function($, window, undefined) {
    var hasOnProgress = ("onprogress" in $.ajaxSettings.xhr());

    if (!hasOnProgress) {
        return;
    }
    
    var oldXHR = $.ajaxSettings.xhr;
    $.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {

        var xhr = oldXHR();

 if(usersAgent == 'IE'){
   ?????????
 }
     
        if(usersAgent != 'IE'){
        
         //Получение данных с сервера
         xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){  
          //Получаю данные Размер/Скачено и изменяю размер статус бара
         }, false);
         
                //Загрузка данных на сервер
         xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) { 
          //Получаю данные Размер/Загружено и изменяю размер статус бара
     }, false);
      
 }
        
        return xhr;
    };
})(jQuery, window);
```

и все везде работает кроме IE11, как я понял на нем не работает **addEventListener**, но я так и не понял чем его заменить? Перепробовал все что можно было нагуглить, но ничего не работает.

**Ответ на комментарий ниже:**
К сожалению нет, как я понял на IE11 вообще не работает addEventListener, и надо использовать альтернативы типа onreadystatechange, но и она у меня толкам не работает, либо я не правильно ее использую, либо есть другие методы..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829292/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-error-in-ie11 оно не?